# No Basic Camera UI for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

OK. Questions.

1. I know there is no CameraCaptureUI in Windows phone 8.1, so I have to use MediaCapture class. That's fine but what about UI? Do I have to make and position button in my screen from scratch?(like flash button, front camera button etc)
2. About Nokia Imaging SDK.  does it provide any UI? and can I use that API for taking picture instead of working directly with MediaCapture?.  I tried to find out some information about initializing and taking picture using nokia imaging sdk, but I couldn't find.
3. Can you let me know any useful link for implementing MediaCapture in windows phone 8.1? There are lots of links but only for silverlight 8.0 not 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FileOpenPicker and if you specify .png and .jpg in the list of file types, the picker will have a camera capture button that will open standard camera capture UI:

```
  FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

  picker.ContinuationData["Data"] = "Something"; // Will be passed back to the app after the picker finishes

  picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

If you still want to write your own UI, check this link: http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/

Comment: great! picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
gave me alot of problems with back key