# About Camera UI in window phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How to access to Standard Camera Capture UI from code in winphone 8.1?
I tried FileOpenPicker to open Picture Library (added button to access camera on navigation bar). Is there any another way to access Camera Capture UI than using FileOpenPicker, for example- custom UI with class MediaCapture or is it not a good idea to use MediaCapture for simple capturing image? It mean, Can I call to Standard Camera Capture UI if I know what happen when click button camera in FileOpenPicker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Basic Camera UI for Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392977/no-basic-camera-ui-for-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there isn't one in Phone 8.1, see here: [CameraCaptureTask missing in Window Phone 8.1 runtime???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283066/cameracapturetask-missing-in-window-phone-8-1-runtime)

You can use the FileOpenPicker to let the user choose an existing image or if they so choose, they can capture on in the moment by tapping the camera button in the app bar.

Windows Phone 10 is set to bring this back, as far as I know.